# Wrong date after reboot ... always the same... 2016-10-02 (future!)

Tags: ntp

Why my Raspberry after reboot sets date to `2016-10-02`, every time?

Date after reboot is exactly `2016-10-02` every time.... there is NTP deamon that changes it, but before it, it's always `2016-10-02`...

Comment: Does it have internet connectivity?

Comment: Are you sure that isn't the past?  What does `date` actually say?

Comment: date after reboot is exactly 2016-10-02 every time.... there is NTP deamon that changes it, but before it, it's always 2016-10-02... shouldn't it be last before reboot?

Comment: How do you reboot it?

Comment: `sudo reboot` .